# Cannot console log api results in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This could be the simplest thing, but my console log below is not working to see the api results, can anyone see why, I am new to React BTW.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true })
    console.log('app mounted');
    fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=8')
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ data: data.articles, loading: false}))
        console.log('Results -', JSON.stringify(this.data));
}
```

Comment: Perhaps add where the function is called?

Comment: It looks like you're logging outside of the fetch return. The data is not yet available. Move the log statement inside the final `then` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have accepted answer and upvoted both your input.

Comment: Are you sure my answer is not correct? Do you see an `undefined` being logged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log the results in the callback of the `setState` function like this:

```
this.setState({ data: data.articles, loading: false}, () => console.log(data.articles))
```

Comment: Yep. If you try to log `this.state.data` outside of the callback, it will often come up with the previous result since `this.setState` is asynchronous by nature.

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing you need to know I that you are working with `Promises` here. Promises are `asynchronous`, which means if you would write these lines of code

```
let a = "a"

fetch('https://newsapi.org/...')
  .then(() => { a = "b"; }

console.log(a) // "a"
```

The result would be `a` because JavaScript will start whatever is creating a `Promise` (in this case `fetch`) and then go on with the lines following that (in this case `console.log(a)`). The `.then` parts will be executed when the promise has finished whatever it is doing, in your case waiting for the network traffic to come back.

So what happens in your case is

```
// You set the state
this.setState({ loading: true })

// You log
console.log('app mounted');

// You create a promise
fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=8')
    // all of these then things will be called when the network traffic finishes
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ data: data.articles, loading: false}))

    // this line is not part of the then so this is what actually gets called next
    // so here you are still logging the original state of this.data not the one after the network traffic
    console.log('Results -', JSON.stringify(this.data));


    // some time in the future your thens will be executed
```

Also the second thing here is that you are logging `this.data`. You actually want to log `this.state.data`. So your code should look like this

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true })
    console.log('app mounted');
    fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=8')
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ data: data.articles, loading: false}))
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Results', this.state.data);
        })

}
```

Comment: Logging in the last `then` like that is a race-condition since `setState` doesn't return a Promise.

Comment: Ok, but the bigger problem is more about the insane race condition of logging before the fetch has retuned. If anything you need to have a combination of both

Comment: Logging before the fetch is not a race-condition, it just won't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your `console.log('Results -', JSON.stringify(this.data));` is executing even before the data is returned.

So to console log the result:

put console.log as a callback to setState, since it is an asynchronous function:

```
fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=8')
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ data: data.articles, loading: false}, () => {'Results -', JSON.stringify(data)}));
```